# Showing hidden div if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have two checkboxes. The checkBoxValidate function triggered by "onclick" assures that the two checkboxes cannot be both selected at the same time. The showMe function, also triggered by "onclick", displays a hidden div when check box is clicked. Everything just fine.

The problem:

When clicking on checkbox1 and then on checkbox2, the div triggered by checkbox1 is not automatically hidden. The idea is than when a checkbox is not selected the div triggered by it should not be visible... Please look at the demo.

Thank you!

DEMO:

http://jsbin.com/iNuPAREq/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
<form action="whatever" name="comanda11" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">

<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('content1'); checkBoxValidate(0);">

<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick=" showMe('content2'); checkBoxValidate(1);">

<div id="content1" style="display:none">
Content 1
</div>

<div id="content2" style="display:none">
Content 2
</div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
    function showMe(box) {
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        var vis = "none";
        for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
            if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                vis = "block";
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
    }

    function checkBoxValidate(cb) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (eval("document.comanda11.c1[" + j + "].checked") == true) {
                document.comanda11.c1[j].checked = false;
                if (j == cb) {
                    document.comanda11.c1[j].checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth aren't you just using radio buttons ?

Comment: In fact, that also came to my mind. Why not radio? Can't you do show/hide on click of radio

Comment: Too add to @adeneo's question, usually checkboxes are used to indicate multiple independent options, when more than one can be selected at a time.  Radio buttons are usually used when you want to choose from between multiple, mutually exclusive options.  You don't have to do it this way, but it would take advantage of conforming to user expectations.

Comment: Not a very neat solution, but it works.

http://jsbin.com/iNuPAREq/3/edit

Comment: Before your `for` loop, go ahead and hide both divs. Let the for loop turn the correct one back on.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! harsha's solution did the trick, I just had to copy/paste the script. Will consider switching to radio buttons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but it works for your situation

```
function showMe (box) {
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        var vis = "none";
        document.getElementById("content1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content2").style.display = "none"; 
        for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) 
        { 
          if(chboxs[i].checked)
          {
             vis = "block";
                break;
           }
        }
        document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;  

}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! harsha's solution did the trick, I just had to copy/paste the script. Will consider switching to radio buttons!

Answer (score 1):

change the markup to use radio buttons, and remove the inline javascript:

```
<form action="whatever" name="comanda11" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="c1" data-rel="content1" />
    <input type="radio" name="c1" data-rel="content2" />
    <div id="content1" style="display:none">Content 1</div>
    <div id="content2" style="display:none">Content 2</div>
</form>
```

then do

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('c1');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
        elems[i].addEventListener ('change',fn,false);
    }else if (elems[i].attachEvent) {
        elems[i].attachEvent ('onchange',fn); 
    }
}

function fn() {
    var rel = this.getAttribute('data-rel');
    document.getElementById(rel=='content1'?'content2':'content1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(rel).style.display = 'block';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzJ5n/)

If you just have to use checkboxes, here's a working solution:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('c1');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
        elems[i].addEventListener ('change',fn,false);
    }else if (elems[i].attachEvent) {
        elems[i].attachEvent ('onchange',fn); 
    }
}

function fn() {
    var rel   = this.getAttribute('data-rel');

    for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
        if (elems[i] != this) elems[i].checked = false;
        var id = elems[i].getAttribute('data-rel');
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = elems[i].checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzJ5n/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get this to behave correctly is to set all divs to hidden before setting the div selected to `block`.

```
var divs = [document.getElementsByName("content1"),document.getElementsByName("content2")];
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++_ {
    divs[i].style.display = 'none'
}
```

The above code should go above
`document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;`

Note that There are much better ways to work with DOM elements.  I would recommend looking into jQuery as a much simpler way of doing this.  Also, manually building an array of two div elements is not the best way to do this, but I don't want to risk grabbing other divs that might be in your document.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I set a global variable to the div being displayed at the time it is "unhidden". lets call it "lastdiv" as an example.

```
var lastdiv=false;
function showme(){
 if(lastdiv){lastdiv.style.display='none';}
 lastdiv=?????? // your code to find the div to unhide
 lastdiv.style.display='block';
}
```

You have lots of other issues in your code to work out including the use of eval in a situation where it is clearly not warranted. There are better ways to do it without using eval.